# Allow accessing a file only from specific URL in HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess

I have no idea how to block entering to a specific file from every one except one website. I Have 2 websites, one with my website and other that I can upload to him any thing I want to. I want to allow image uploading to my website, but really it will upload the image to the other website, using `AJAX`. But I don't want people to be able to use the `AJAX` code for their sites too, I want that the other website will allow image uploading (AKA accessing to the `PHP` upload file) only from the first website.

I do not know how to use `HTACCESS`, I know only the basic, so here is an a example in PHP (and please help me to 'translate' it to `HTACCESS`):

```
<?php

     if($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] == "/images/uploads/EXAMPLE" && $from != "http://www.example.com"){ // $from = from where the ajax request were sent.
          header("location: 403.html");
     }

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can give this a try, put the content below in your .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIf Referer my-domain.com internal 
# 
<Files *> 
order Deny,Allow 
Deny from all 
Allow from env=internal 
</Files>
```

Put the .htaccess file in website where you upload the image to. My-Domain.com is the domain that you would like to have access to the images.

Note: This is not tested

Comment: `my-domain.com` it the domain that sends the AJAX request? I need to open a HTACCESS file on the uploading folder and add it there or to the main HTACCESS file?

Comment: **Tested: works perfectly**.
 I set `internal` as a specific page, I **can't access my private folder by the URL**, I **can't access it from others pages** of my website **except the specific one** I entered. It's pretty useful to protect private files access and there's not much tips on how to do it, thanks a lot !